# executor service. how to await while all threads will terminate

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Please help to understand concurrency problem.

I have following code for thread execution:

```
public void startPool(final Processor processor, Configuration config) {
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(config.getThreadPoolSize());
            for (final String source : config.getSourcePaths()) {
                pool.submit(new Runnable() {
    
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        processor.process(source);
    
                    }
                });
            }
            pool.shutdown();
        }
```

When I use 1 thread(`config.getThreadPoolSize()` returns 1) I get expecetd result.

When I use another thread count - every time I get different results. In my case result - is output to console. I understand that if I use a lot of threads I can get different order of output but I get  different content!!! Sometimes, contents is absent. Looks like one thread terminated and other died at that moment.

Where can I search error? at this code or somewhere deeper?

I see this situation like on picture:

[image]

### UPDATE:

If rewrite code like this:

```
           @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized ("123") {
                    processor.process(source);
                }
            }
```

it is working but as I understand it is not multithreading)

### update

Problem was that threadpool swallows exceptions. I could resolve my problem after catching throwable inside the  `processor.process(source);` and printStackTrace

Comment: So you have non-thread-safe code, most probably. But how are we supposed to find you error without knowing your code? It’s not the `Executor` which is responsible to make your code thread-safe.

Comment: @Holger ok. thanks. Now I know that this code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `Processor` implementation you use is **not thread-safe**: you get the expected output for 1 thread but not for several threads in parallel.

The behavior may be unexpected in a multi threaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown%28%29) --> 
    shutdown()
This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination() to do that.

Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: at this case my application is hang